# How I can separate integer number in 3 "houses"? Hundred, Ten and Unity

Tags: c

I have, for example, a variable

`int number = 300;`

And I need modify "number" by "number", I wonder if I need separate in 3 variables for hundred, ten, unity or if there a method for divide that enable to me change a unique variable "number' by "number", "house" by "house", a hundred, a ten and unity (3 - 2 - 1).

Example: The user need only change number "2" of 3'2'1, and he want that "2" to being "5", as "321" must become to "351". In other words, the number 3 and 0 not will modified, only number 2 from 321, turning 3-5-1.

Comment: Asked to move the question to stackoverflow as it is not related to Arduino.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with Arduino, it is C.

You can for example convert this to an array with `itoa()` (see https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/PrintingNumbers/)

And then convert it back to int with `atoi()` (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that, e.g. by using a function to change the digit.

Use the following steps:

1. What you do, is first shifting the digit right until it is the most right digit and remember the part removed
2. Clear the last digit.
3. Add the new digit
4. Shift left
5. Add the remembered part

Example (same steps as above) to change 321 to 351:

1. Shift right gives 32. Remember 1
2. Use the modulo operator and remove it: 32 - (32 % 10) = 32 - 2 = 30
3. 30 + 5 = 35
4. 35 -> after shift gives 350
5. 350 + 1 = 351

I will leave the implementation up to you.

Comment: To save space and time, should I create a function that does this automatically, passing the integer as a parameter? Does the function independent of the total amount of digits (eg 200 or 2000).

Comment: Yes, create one function that does all these 5 steps and call it for every digit you want to change (if you want to changer every digit, you better can write simply a = 100 * x + 10 * y + z).  I haven't tested it but digit 0 is the most right one (the least significant), and it should work for all numbers (as long as it fits in an integer).